# how setting function after a few minutes run again in Django

Tags: django, schedule

I trying make a auto function in Django
i reseached all afternoon i tried with library  Selery but i can't
I try this but fail

setting.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Makassar'
from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'MultiLevelApp.tasks.task_number_one',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    }
}
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from .views import autocheck

@shared_task
def task_number_one():
    autocheck()
    print("check")
```

viewss.py

```
from .tasks import task_number_one

task_number_one()
```

end it just run 1 times [enter image description here]

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: sr I didn't make it clear, it doesn't run repeatedly but only runs every first time

Comment: You say "it fails". What do you mean by that? Do you see an error traceback? Does your PC turns off? Do you hear any noises?

Comment: function task_number_one()     only run once and it doesn't repeat

Comment: It seems as an exepcted output.